How request, header, query and other parameters are injected into dependency function internally in FastAPI?
Fast api has builtin mechanism to call and provide request parameter i.e q, offset, header and many more to dependency function, but internally from where dependency function is being executed and passed parameter.
from typing import Annotated, Union

from fastapi import Depends, FastAPI

app = FastAPI()


async def common_parameters(
    q: Union[str, None] = None, skip: int = 0, limit: int = 100
):
    return {"q": q, "skip": skip, "limit": limit}


@app.get("/items/")
async def read_items(commons: Annotated[dict, Depends(common_parameters)]):
    return commons


@app.get("/users/")
async def read_users(commons: Annotated[dict, Depends(common_parameters)]):
    return commons


From where the common_parameter is being called with param? Depends is function that takes dependency function as argument and return params.Depends which is class. And that class has only repr and init method. I have expected there is call method from where it execute common_parameter function. I just want to know how parameters are being passed dynamically?

You can see the get_dependant implementation here: https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/blob/3425c834cc113060d00b8a295d3456eb306a109d/fastapi/dependencies/utils.py#L241 - the dependency classes are just specifications of the dependency, they do not parse and resolve the arguments expected to an endpoint. The "starting" point for registering dependencies is in the APIRouter: https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/blob/3425c834cc113060d00b8a295d3456eb306a109d/fastapi/routing.py#L389
